How to make Mixamo model face realistic -- fuse Face Builder mesh at the neck?
I'm trying to recreate a historical figure in Blender.
I recreated his face using Face Builder, and have downloaded an animated body from Mixamo who I'm going to create Victorian clothing for.
Is there a way I can make the face on this Mixamo body realistic like what I made using Face Builder, either by attaching the Face Builder head mesh onto it, or through some other process?
I thought of simply deleting the head mesh from the Mixamo body, and joining the Face Builder head onto it, but the Mixamo animation doesn't 'connect' with the foreign head...

Set the armature to rest pose, make sure that both head and body meshes have the same rot and scale values (if needed, press Ctrl A > Apply rot and scale).
Select the new head, shift select the mixamo character (it has to be the last selected, "Active" object, outlined with yellow, not orange), press ctrl J to join them.
Then go to edit mode, search for the "Head" Vertex Group, select all new head vertices and click the "Assign" button.


Thank you, solved!
